# Web Development - Should social login be performed on frontend or handled on the backend of and application?

Tags: django, facebook

I am building a social login based application using Django on the backend and I want to know whether it is a good practice to do Social Auth(facebook, google, github, twitter etc.) on the front end or the backend of an application?

For example, If I want to allow a user to signup using their facebook account, is it a good idea to handle that using JavaScript on the front end or using Django on the backend(e.g, using something like social_auth_app_django)?

Answer (score 1):

Both sides =) The authToken you store should placed in your backend while the session interaction could be done with the frontend.

If you are a beginner ,My recommendation is to go with **Django Social Auth**.

Django Social Auth is an easy way to setup social authentication/authorization mechanism for Django projects.

docs : http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.io

github :https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

**Installation:**

```
pip install django-social-auth
```